# SQL Database Schema - Many to Many or Pivot Table

Tags: sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a proper database layout for a project I'm working on, however I can't seem to work out which is best.

Basically the "app" is something where a User can be assigned to many Products, and a Product can be have many Customers.

From here, each Customer has a Service, which is specific to that Customer and Product.

A Service can have many Incidents, but an Incident can only be assigned to one Service.

A User can also have Incidents, but an Incident can only have one User.

Here is the two designs I have made for this:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN81k.png

As you can see, the left design has a table specific tables for the Many-Many relationships, where as the right one has a overall pivot table for them all.

I see both of these methods working (in my head) - however since I'm not the best with this, are there any downsides to either of these methods? And do you see any problems I'll run into, in the future?

Also, is the right one even a proper way of doing it?

I'm also going to be using the Eloquent ORM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up 'Third Normal Form'. This gives rules on how to design tables. You could take one or other of your current designs and apply the three rules to see where you get to.

I would say the one on the right is wrong: too much duplicate information, and unclear relationships. The one on the left is OK, but the two Many-Many tables are redundant. You know a Product and Customer are linked because it's in the Service table. You know a User and Product are linked because its in the Incident + Service tables.

Cheers -

After clarification, a User belongs to a Customer. In that case, add CustomerID to the User table - this is important data about the user and should be included. It will allow you to stop the User raising Incidents on Products not associated with the Customer.
This also will enable you to list the Products associated with the User via the Customer the User is associated with.
Further, the Customer should have it's ID on Product, and Service should have the ProductId, not the CustomerID, as the Service is associated with a Product and only with a Customer via the Product it is associated with.

Comment: Ah okay, so I see the point about the Products and Customers - understand that.  But for Users and Products, are you saying that to access what Products/Customers a User has, you find all of his Incidents, and therefore the services? Or create a Many-Many table between Users - Services?

Comment: I'd have to know a bit more about the domain. What's the difference between a User and a Customer? What relationship do they have?

Comment: @simonatrcl From what I understand, Larry Page & Sergey Brin would be the Users.  Google would be the customer.  Gmail, Hangouts, Google+ would be the products.  Web Services, API's, Firewalls etc would be the services.

Comment: OK, so a User is belongs to a Customer (and only one customer at a time). I'll edit the answer as it gives me more room.

Comment: @simonatrcl A user can have multiple customers. Lets say you owned a company which sold multiple products. A user could be internal or external, but internal users could have multiple customers. A customer can take multiple products.  A product has multiple services.  An incident relates to something to do with that service, however.. multiple products might share the same service, which means an incident could relate to multiple products which could affect multiple customers but only with 1 incident.  Wow thats complicated..

Comment: There are multiple subtleties here! I think telling you what to do isn't going to work, as I don't have the details and will continually get tripped up on one subtlety or another. However, in general: maybe the Many-Many tables do need to come back; I still don't like the customerId on Service as this will mean that a service that has multiple customers will have multiple rows and the relationship is (I think) customer to product to service, not customer to service directly. Read up on Normalising databases: there are good sources out there - http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/ is a good one

Comment: Haha thanks guys, I think this is more complicated that I first thought it would be.  I guess the best approach would be to properly plan out every detail, then go through the normalization stages... rather than just try to jump in at it!

Comment: No problem. Concentrate on the relationships: does a Customer have a direct relationship with a service, or is it indirect via a Product? How many entities are involved with a relationship at each end - a service belongs to one Product and one product has many services, or is it Many-Many? If it really is Many-Many then your linking tables are needed. Cheers -